# Usar Session como Parâmetro de uma consulta

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Olá, possuo um método para faz o login do sistema, logo após necessito que o usuário selecione uma opção em um dropdown e guardo esse valor em uma session.
Agora preciso de colocar o valor armazenado na session, dentro de uma consulta LINQ.
Vou postar os códigos, que irão compreender melhor.

Metodo para armazenar o dado em uma session:

```
 public ActionResult Contrato()
    {      
        var contrato = new Usuario() { SqContrato = 0 };

        return View(contrato);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contrato(Int16? Contrato)
    {

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Contrato"] = Contrato;

        return View();
    }
```

Método onde preciso colocar o valor armazenado pela session:

```
    public ViewResult Ferias()
    {
        var usuarios =
            funcionarioFeriasRepository.Lista.Where(r => r.slogin == autenticacaoProvider.UsuarioAutenticado.Login && r.SqContrato == "SESSION AQUI"
                .ToList();

        return View(usuarios);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça um Helper:

```
public static class SessionHelper
{
    public static int Contrato {
        get { return (int)HttpContext.Current.Session['Contrato']; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session['Contrato'] = value; }
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
public ViewResult Ferias()
{
    var contrato = SessionHelper.Contrato;
    var usuarios =
        funcionarioFeriasRepository.Lista.Where(r => r.slogin == autenticacaoProvider.UsuarioAutenticado.Login && r.SqContrato == contrato)
            .ToList();

    return View(usuarios);
}
```

Comment: Ao criar o Helper, eu recebo o seguinte erro: "PortalRH.WebUI.Models.SessionHelper.Contrato: cannot declare instance members in a static class", sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Erro meu mesmo. Editei a resposta.

Comment: Na parte do Get{return HttpContext.Current.Session["Contrato"];} recebo o seguinte erro:
"cannot convert expression type 'object' to return type int"

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Editei novamente

Comment: Entre o "(int)" e o "return" eu recebo o "Expression Expected"( mas não fala qual). E no restante eu continuo com o mesmo erro.
"cannot convert expression type 'object' to return type int"

Comment: Fiz um convertTo, e funcionou.
 get {  return Convert.ToInt16(HttpContext.Current.Session["Contrato"]); }

Comment: Obrigado Cigano Morrison Mendez, me ajudou bastante.